# ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for input_word_ids

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, tf.keras

AM trying to connect the encoder and decoder for a abstractive text summarization with a set of hidden states and layers added to the typical. I changed my embedder from BERt to longformer thinking it will solve the problem however it is not.

The error keeps popping up:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4096), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_word_ids'), name='input_word_ids', description="created by layer 'input_word_ids'") at layer "tf_longformer_model_9". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

```
from transformers import LongformerTokenizer, TFLongformerModel
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, LSTM, Attention, Concatenate, Dropout, Dense, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TimeDistributed, Lambda, Add

# Load a pre-trained Longformer tokenizer
tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')

# Define the maximum sequence length for Longformer
max_length = 4096  # Adjust as needed based on your GPU memory and sequence length requirements

# Tokenize and convert your text data to Longformer input features
def tokenize_text(text, max_length):
    # Tokenize the text and truncate/pad it to the specified max_length
    inputs = tokenizer(text, padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=max_length, return_tensors="tf")
    return inputs
# Assume max_length and vocab_size are defined
max_length = 4096
vocab_size = 40000

# Encoder
input_word_ids = Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
input_mask = Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_mask")
longformer_model = TFLongformerModel.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')
encoder_outputs = longformer_model(input_word_ids, attention_mask=input_mask).last_hidden_state

# Correcting variable names to reflect the actual outputs and inputs
longformer_outputs = longformer_model(input_word_ids, attention_mask=input_mask)
longformer_sequence_output = Lambda(lambda x: x, name="longformer_sequence_output")(longformer_outputs.last_hidden_state)

# Apply the convolutional layer
cnn_layer = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding='same', name="cnn_layer")(longformer_sequence_output)

# Add dropout after CNN layer
cnn_dropout = Dropout(0.5, name="cnn_dropout")(cnn_layer)

# Modify LSTM layer to return states along with the sequence output
lstm_layer, state_h, state_c = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name="lstm_layer")(cnn_dropout)

# LSTM states
lstm_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Add dropout after LSTM layer
lstm_dropout = Dropout(0.5, name="lstm_dropout")(lstm_layer)

# Implement the auxiliary attention mechanism
auxiliary_attention = Attention(name="auxiliary_attention")([lstm_dropout, lstm_dropout])

# Combine the main and auxiliary attention mechanisms
combined_attention = Concatenate(name="combined_attention")([lstm_dropout, auxiliary_attention])  # Encoder output

# Reducing the dimensionality of the encoder outputs before passing to the attention layer
encoder_dim_reduction = Dense(256, activation='relu', name="encoder_dim_reduction")(combined_attention)

# Create the encoder model
encoder_model = Model(inputs=[input_word_ids, input_mask], outputs=[encoder_dim_reduction, state_h, state_c], name="encoder_model")

# Print the summary to see the model architecture
encoder_model.summary()

decoder_dim = 256

# Decoder
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_inputs')
coverage_input = Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype=tf.float32, name="coverage_input")
initial_h = Input(shape=(256,), name='initial_h')
initial_c = Input(shape=(256,), name='initial_c')

# Embedding layer for the decoder
decoder_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=decoder_dim, name='decoder_embedding')
decoder_embedded = decoder_embedding(decoder_inputs)

# Decoder LSTM
decoder_lstm = LSTM(decoder_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name='decoder_lstm')
decoder_lstm_out, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_embedded, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])

# Attention Layer
attention_layer = Attention(use_scale=True, name='attention_layer')
attention_out, attention_weights = attention_layer([decoder_lstm_out, encoder_dim_reduction], return_attention_scores=True)

# Coverage mechanism: update the coverage vector
coverage_update_layer = Add(name="coverage_update")
updated_coverage = coverage_update_layer([coverage_input, Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=-1))(attention_weights)])

# Reducing the dimensionality of the coverage to match the attention output
coverage_projection = TimeDistributed(Dense(decoder_dim), name="coverage_projection")(updated_coverage[:, tf.newaxis])

# Combine LSTM output, attention output, and coverage vector
decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name="decoder_concat_input")([decoder_lstm_out, attention_out, coverage_projection])

# Dense layer to generate probabilities over the vocabulary
output_layer = TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'), name='output_layer')
decoder_outputs = output_layer(decoder_concat_input)

# Pointer-generator layer for copy mechanism
pointer_generator = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="pointer_generator")(decoder_concat_input)

# Final Decoder Model
decoder_model = Model(
    inputs=[decoder_inputs, initial_h, initial_c, coverage_input],
    outputs=[decoder_outputs, updated_coverage, pointer_generator],
    name='decoder_model'
)

decoder_outputs, updated_coverage, pointer_generator = decoder_model(
    [decoder_inputs, state_h, state_c, coverage_input]
)

# Print the summary to inspect the model architecture
decoder_model.summary()
```